# What's the measure of the segment $MD$ in the triangle below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference:

> In the figure, calculate $MD$, if $BM = 6\ \mathrm m$, $DE= 1\ \mathrm m$ and *$M$ is incenter* *. (Answer:$2\ \mathrm m$)

*<sup>(Added later)</sup>

[image]

My progress: I found a solution on the net but the consideration of point $M$ being the incentre (<s>not mentioned</s>) was made in the statement besides using more advanced trigonometry. Would it be possible to solve it by geometry <s>and without considering M as incenter</s>?

Let $M$ = incenter triangle $ABC$

By Incenter Theorems:

$\displaystyle \frac{MB}{MD} = \frac{a+c}{b} \iff \frac{BD}{MD} = \frac{a+b+c}b \iff MD = \frac{b}{2p} \cdot BD = \frac b{2p} \cdot \frac{2ac \cdot \cos \frac{B}2}{a+c} \implies \\\displaystyle 
MB = \frac{ac \cos \frac{B}2}{p}\\ \displaystyle
EM = EA = EC = \frac{\frac b2}{\cos \frac B2} = \frac b{2\cos \frac B2}$

Using a non-trivial relationship

$\displaystyle ac \cos^2 \frac B2 = p(p-b) \implies \\\displaystyle
\frac{MB}{ME} = \frac{2(p-b)}b \iff \frac{6}{1 + MD} = \frac{a+c - b}{b} = \frac{MB}{MD} -1\\\displaystyle
\implies \frac6{1+x} = \frac6x -1 \iff x=2$

Original Problem:

[image]

Comment: No if $M$ is not fixed or there is no more info, there is no unique solution.

Comment: is BP and BQ are tangent to the smaller circle

Comment: @MathLover Is there a solution by geometry considering M incenter?

Comment: @Bometh  yes, it is.

Comment: @petaarantes not sure, the question itself isn't very clear to me.

Comment: @MathLover  Is triangle $BPQ$ is isosceles since $BP$ and $BQ$ are tangent to the same point and since $PM$ = $MQ$, $BM$ would be perpendicular to $PQ$?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Can you link the source?

Comment: @ACB   I have posted above the original problem

Comment: I now see your edit to the question that $M$ is incenter. That makes a geometric solution possible. See my answer.

Comment: *"I found a solution on the net.."* is it possible to share that also :) ?

Comment: @ACB  When I said "on the net" the truth is this solution was taken from another forum in my country...it is not from a specific site..

Comment: @petaarantes ... if you are still interested in this question and if I can address the original version of this question, please see [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4322021/997661).

Comment: @A-B-C gratidude...very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say, $MD = x$. As $M$ is the incenter of $\triangle ABC$,

$ \displaystyle \frac{BM}{MD} = \frac{a+c}b$

$ \displaystyle  \implies \frac 6x = \frac{a+c}b\tag1$

$ \displaystyle CD = \frac{ab}{a+c}\tag2$

As $\triangle ADE \sim \triangle BDC$ and $AE = ME$,

$ \displaystyle \frac{AE}{DE} = \frac{BC}{CD}$
$ \displaystyle \implies ME = MD + DE = x + 1 = \frac{a+c}b ~  \left[\text {using } (2)\right]$

Plugging into $(1)$,

$ \displaystyle \frac 6 x = x + 1 \implies (x-2)(x+3) = 0$

That leads to $x = 2$.

---

$AE = CE = ME$ is always true if $M$ is the incenter of $\triangle ABC$ and $E$ is the point where the angle bisector of $\angle B$ intersects the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$. See below -

$ \displaystyle \angle CAE = \frac{\angle B} 2, \angle MAC = \frac{\angle A}2$
$ \displaystyle \implies \angle MAE = \frac{\angle B + \angle A}2 = 90^\circ - \frac{\angle C}2$

Also, $ \displaystyle \angle MEA = \angle C \implies \angle AME = 90^\circ - \frac{\angle C}2 = \angle MAE$

$\therefore AE = ME$

Comment: I am wondering why it is given that PM=MQ...

Comment: @ACB I agree with you. Once we know $M$ is incenter, that is immaterial and so is the inner circle. But if we did not know $M$ was incenter, it does help us realize that $BE$ is angle bisector.

Comment: As you said, we can determine that BE is angle bisector. Also we can see that the inner circle is tangent to two sides of the triangle and to the circumcircle at the same time. And we have segments with fixed lengths. So there maybe a way to show M is the incentre, without assuming that.

Comment: @MathLover .. I have found a [way](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4322021/997661) to prove that M is the incentre. But I don't know how to prove this (which completes the answer): "*Consider two orthogonal circles. Draw a line through the centre of one circle which cuts the other circle at A and B. Any circle through A and B is orthogonal to the first one*". Do you know a proof or any theorem which states this? (Sorry to bother you)

Comment: @MathLover ... Thanks for the source. By the way, I have found another answer to my question which does not involve the above. I'll will post it in a few hours .... FYI: I asked the second question also here, where I was given the same reference you gave :)

Comment: @MathLover ... I posted the answer. Please go through the link above. I think that solves this problem as well.