# A set of orthogonal circles passing through two points

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, plane-geometry

This is related to my previous problem: [Relation between incentre of a triangle and a circle touching its two sides and circumcircle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4322021/997661) , where I have found an answer but stuck at the following fact.

> Given two orthogonal circles ($c$ and $d$) draw a line passing through the centre of one circle $(O)$ and intersecting the other circle at points $A$ and $B$. Any circle passing through $A$ and $B$ is orthogonal to $\odot O$.
>
> [image: img]

I believe this is a well-known property (not known to me). Is there any specific theorem which states this? Or do you have a proof?

Comment: See the [properties of the radical axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_axis#Orthogonal_circles)

Comment: Another way to look at it is: Doing [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry#Circle_inversion) with respect to $c$, the circle $d$ transforms onto itself, since it is orthogonal to the circle of inversion. Therefore, $A$ is the inverse of $B$. Any other circle passing through $A$ and $B$ will have to map onto itself by the inversion, and therefore, be orthogonal to $c$.

Comment: Another way is by [power of a point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point): If $T$ is a point of intersection of $c$ and $d$, then $OT$ is tangent to $d$. Then $OT^2=OA\cdot OB$. For another circle passing through $A$ and $B$ we are going to have the same power of the point of $O$ with respect to that circle. Therefore, the length of the tangent from $O$ to that new circle will also be equal in length to $OT$, the radius of $c$. Therefore, the new tangency point is on the circle $c$. Hence $c$ and the new circle are also orthogonal.

Comment: @Boxwood , thanks for help.