Find the segment "MD" in the internally tangent circles below
In the figure calculate $MD$.
$BM = 6m$, $DE= 1m$.
$BD \cap PQ = M$

I try:
Let $N$ be the upper intersection of the segment $BE$ with the smaller circle
$AD.DC = DE.BD = DE.(6+MD)$
$\therefore AD.DC = MD+6$
$BP^2 = BN.BE = BN.(BM+MD+DE) = BN(7+MD)$
$BP = BQ$

@ACB But in that old answer point $M$ is taken to be the incenter of $ABC$, which is not explicitly stated and should be proved.

I think the OP should explain the difference between this question and the old one, if they don't want this to be closed as duplicate.

@Intelligentipauca that fact 'M is the incentre' was added after MathLover's answer. Originally it was this exact question. And if you look at the linked posts there, you will find some information about why M has to be the incentre. You may also want to read the comments there :)

@Intelligentipauca and "ACB" I apologize because it would actually be the same text as the question posted 2 years ago... It was a coincidence but they are from different sources so as it has already been resolved the administrator can close the question
Thank you all

@ACB I hadn't noticed, in fact, that a link to a proof that $M$ is the incenter of $ABC$ had been posted in the comments: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4322021/255730 Nonetheless, I think there could be a more direct proof, not relying on $M$ being the incenter.
